# Function maximized by $\left\{\left\lfloor\frac np\right\rfloor,\dots,\left\lfloor\frac{n+p-j}p\right\rfloor\right\}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Since [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4347837/943723) MSE question didn't find any suitable answers, I decided to post it here.

I was trying to maximize the function
$$f(r)=\binom nr\cdot 2^{n-r}$$
This can be done by the standard technique of looking at $\frac {f(r)}{f(r+1)}$ and the answer we get is that $r=\left\lfloor\frac n3\right\rfloor$ if $n=3k$ or $n=3k+1$, and $r=\left\lfloor\frac n3\right\rfloor, \left\lfloor\frac {n+1}3\right\rfloor$ if $n=3k+2$. So, we can also say that the *maximizing set* of $f(r)=\binom nr\cdot 2^{n-r}$ is the set $\mathcal M_2=\left\{\left\lfloor\frac n3\right\rfloor, \left\lfloor\frac {n+1}3\right\rfloor\right\}$. Note that this set is irrespective of the modulo class of $n$ (as $\mathcal M_2=\{k,k\}=\{k\}$if $n=3k$ or $n=3k+1$).

I was trying to play with this idea and figured out that if for some $p\in \mathbb N$, we define
$$f(r)=\binom nr\cdot (p-1)^{n-r}$$
then the *maximizing set* is $\mathcal M_{p-1}=\left\{\left\lfloor\frac np\right\rfloor, \left\lfloor\frac {n+1}p\right\rfloor\right\}$.

I tried to play a little bit more with the *maximizing set* and started thinking about the set
$$\mathcal M=\left\{\left\lfloor\frac np\right\rfloor, \left\lfloor\frac {n+1}p\right\rfloor, \dots ,\left\lfloor\frac {n+p-j}p\right\rfloor\right\}$$
where $0\leq j\leq p$. Note that $\mathcal M$ still has only atmost $2$ elements since if $n=pk+i$, then
$$\left\{\left\lfloor\frac np\right\rfloor, \left\lfloor\frac {n+1}p\right\rfloor, \dots ,\left\lfloor\frac {n+p-j}p\right\rfloor\right\}=\{k\}\text{  if }i<j$$
$$\left\{\left\lfloor\frac np\right\rfloor, \left\lfloor\frac {n+1}p\right\rfloor, \dots ,\left\lfloor\frac {n+p-j}p\right\rfloor\right\}=\{k,k+1\}\text{  if }i\geq j$$

My question is, **is there any combinatorial function that is maximized by $\mathcal M$**? In other words, is there any combinatorial function $f_n(r)$ whose *maximizing set* is $\mathcal M$? I tried to construct some multinomials, but couldn't proceed much. I would like to have some ideas.

**Edit**: Since mutinomials didn't help, I was thinking in terms of graphs. If we consider a graph of a binomial, it has the typical binomial structure. What we are trying to achieve is to shift the maxima of that structure accordingly as $j$. So, it may happen that the function we are looking for is the binomial multiplied with some constant. Intuitively, we may even guess that this constant may be a box function involving $j$ somehow in it. But, I couldn't make any more out of this idea. See if it helps.

Comment: I am sorry, but can I ask why $f(r)=2^{-r}\binom{n+1}{r}$ can't serve as an example of maximizing set $\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor,\lfloor\frac{n}{3+1}\rfloor,\lfloor\frac{n+2}{3}\rfloor$? Since when $n=3k+1$ the maximized $r$ is $k+1$.

Comment: @Sayan Dutta I finally got enough reputation to leave a comment. But could you tell me why if $n=3k+1$ than $\lfloor(n+2)/3\rfloor$ is $k+1$? Sorry I may not be fully understanding your problem here.

Comment: @JetfiRex  if $n=3k+1$, then $\frac{n+2}{3}=\frac{3k+3}{3}=\frac{3(k+1)}{3}=k+1$

Comment: @Sayan Dutta Sorry... I am responding your comment two days ago (please refer to that one) and I remember, I mean why $n=3k-1$ (not $n=3k+1$) leads $\lfloor(n+2)/3\rfloor$ is $k+1$... Sorry, but maybe there is a typo.

Comment: @JetfiRex I didn't get that comment. What exactly is your confusion? Ask without any hesitation.

Comment: In the second comment you have said “So, put n=3k−1. Then, ⌊n/3⌋=k−1, ⌊(n+1)/3⌋=k, ⌊(n+2)/3⌋=k+1 and so {⌊n/3⌋, ⌊(n+1)/3⌋, ⌊(n+2)/3⌋}={k−1,k,k+1}, which is not true.”, and this invalidates the function $2^{-r}\binom{n+1}r$. What I am confused is why ⌊(n+2)/3⌋=k+1 here... Please refer to the second comment in the thread... Sorry if I have caused your confusion before.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't help... I mean, you're doing the floor function, not the ceiling function. So I am not really sure why $k+\lfloor1/3 \rfloor$ is $k+1$ instead of $k$... Since $\lfloor1/3 \rfloor$ is $0$, not $1$...

Comment: @JetfiRex forget about everything, I messed up a little bit. Sorry for the confusion. I'll delete the previous comments to avoid further confusions. The answer to your original question is that the function that you suggested, i.e., $f(r)=2^{-r}\binom{n+1}{r}$ has a maxima only at $k$ when $n=3k+1$. But, the set you mentioned, i.e., $\{\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor,\lfloor\frac{n+1}{3}\rfloor,\lfloor\frac{n+2}{3}\rfloor\}=\{k-1,k\}$ gives two different values, namely $k-1$ and $k$. In particular, the maximizing set of the function is $\{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{3}\rfloor,\lfloor\frac{n+2}{3}\rfloor\}$.